# NgForm.valueChanges is not being triggered when form input values are being changed programatically

Tags: angular, angular-forms

In below code snippet, when I change the value of the variable (`selectedBot`) which is bound to form `input` (`name="bot_id"`) programmatically (`(click)="botSelected(bot)` on `<li>`), `form.valueChanges` subscription callback handler is not triggered. However if I type in the input, this callback is being triggered as expected.

I have two question:

1. Why is it happening?
2. How to make it work?

**app.component.html**

```
<p>Selected bot: {{selectedBot.name}}</p>

<form #form="ngForm">

  <div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%">
    <div style="width: 100%">
      <input type="text" id="add" name="bot_id" ngModel placeholder="select a bot" [value]="selectedBot && selectedBot.name || ''">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down center-vertical-absolute"></i>

    </div>
    <ul  class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width: 100%; max-height: 30vh; overflow-y: scroll">
      <li role="menuitem" *ngFor="let bot of botList" (click)="botSelected(bot)"><a
        class="dropdown-item" [ngClass]="{'dropdown-item-active': selectedBot && selectedBot._id===bot._id}">{{bot.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app';
  selectedBot;
  botList = [
    {'_id': 1, name: 'good bot'},
    {'_id': 2, name: 'bad bot'}
  ];
  @ViewChild('form') form: NgForm;


  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log('form data changed', value);
      /*NOT BEING TRIGGEERED WHEN ANY <li> IN <ul> is being clicked*/
    });
  }

  botSelected(bot) {
    this.selectedBot = bot;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger the detection yourself.

```
botSelected(bot) {
  this.selectedBot = bot;
  this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

I would also recommend you use the correct function to set the values of the form. This means using `[(ngModel)]` and `FormControl.prototype.setValue`

**EDIT** Following [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmx92j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), you should simply bind your inputs to a variable with `[(ngModel)]`, and it should work.

Comment: Then use `updateModel`, and start binding your model to your form, as my edit suggests.

Comment: Where did my previous comment go? :D

Comment: Mines are going away too !

Comment: mine too.. scary

Comment: And why doesn't it fits youe use case ? That's the exact same thing as using value : your list of bots will be in the input. If you wish to lock it so the user can't edit it, then don't create an input or set it to disabled.

Comment: You are right. Why do you not recomment to use `[value]`. My question was downvoted...this means I am doing something really wrong. Whats wrong with using `[value]`?

Comment: You can use it if you want, but if you do, you can't expect to listen for changes on your form, because in the eyes of Angular, you don't use one of his forms. And don't mind the votes on your questions, people just vote without giving any reason, sometimes up, sometimes down. If it bothers you, let me upvote your question !

Comment: Thanks. But its not the convincing reason because I have registered the input with the form using ngModel directive.

Comment: You can edit your answer to `this.form.form.updateValueAndValidity()` as @AJT_82 said. It is working for me. I have heard that two way binding causes performance issue, thats why I avoid it unless I really need it.

Comment: So basically, you listened to me to make it work. That's a pretty convincing reason I guess ... And I kind of said it before him actually :P I'm leaving it in my answer, but i stand by my statement that it's part of a `FormGroup`, not a `NgForm`.